# Pandas groupby rank date time

Tags: python, pandas, date, rank

i got an issue over ranking of date times. Lets say i have following table.

```
ID    TIME
01    2018-07-11 11:12:20
01    2018-07-12 12:00:23
01    2018-07-13 12:00:00
02    2019-09-11 11:00:00
02    2019-09-12 12:00:00
```

and i want to add another column to rank the table by time for each id and group. I used

```
df['RANK'] = data.groupby('ID')['TIME'].rank(ascending=True)
```

but get an error:

```
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

If i replace datetime to numbers, it works.... any solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me working convert column to datetimes for avoid your error.

```
data['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIME'])
data['RANK'] = data.groupby('ID')['TIME'].rank(ascending=True)
print (data)
   ID                TIME  RANK
0   1 2018-07-11 11:12:20   1.0
1   1 2018-07-12 12:00:23   2.0
2   1 2018-07-13 12:00:00   3.0
3   2 2019-09-11 11:00:00   1.0
4   2 2019-09-12 12:00:00   2.0
```

Comment: dear Jez, how would you attempt to apply a pd.qcut to this result? is it possible? meaning, instead of making the rank the target result, to have the qcut of the rank as the target result

Comment: @Yuca on phone only, do you try google keywords `pandas groupby qcut`? Maybe there should be some helpful posts.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, there are but nothing specific. I can use qcut and rank independently, but I was trying to do it in one instruction since efficiency is really important. otherwise I have to do 1 groupby to compute the ranks and then another groupby to use the ranks for the qcut. Im using `groupby` + `transform` but i'm super stuck and any help is appreciated