# Pandas Groupby : Get all rows for an ID for the earliest date (large dataset with many ID's)

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df frame with monthly values for an ID and its associated columns. There are "groups" of rows for an ID and the month.  THere may be up to 12 months of data for each ID.
I want all the rows of data for all ID's where the month is the earliest date for each ID

The data looks like

```
    +-------+----+--------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| index | ID |  Date  |      X      |      Y      | Category |
+-------+----+--------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|     0 |  1 | 1/1/18 | 0.118758835 | 0.954677438 | A        |
|     1 |  1 | 1/1/18 | 0.148103273 | 0.976617504 | B        |
|     2 |  1 | 1/1/18 | 0.365541214 | 0.551642346 | C        |
|     3 |  1 | 1/2/18 | 0.405002687 | 0.343279097 | A        |
|     4 |  1 | 1/2/18 | 0.130580643 | 0.144486528 | B        |
|     5 |  1 | 1/2/18 | 0.395113106 | 0.113118681 | C        |
|     6 |  2 | 1/1/18 | 0.425580038 | 0.725166189 | A        |
|     7 |  2 | 1/1/18 | 0.889677796 | 0.386824338 | B        |
|     8 |  2 | 1/1/18 | 0.835311629 | 0.363802849 | C        |
|     9 |  2 | 1/2/18 | 0.8375818   | 0.769265522 | A        |
|    10 |  2 | 1/2/18 | 0.648162611 | 0.075286355 | B        |
|    11 |  2 | 1/2/18 | 0.639060695 | 0.791222309 | C        |
+-------+----+--------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

I am wondering if I  can use Groupby to process the data to output

```
    +-------+----+--------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| index | ID |  Date  |      X      |      Y      | Category |
+-------+----+--------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|     0 |  1 | 1/1/18 | 0.118758835 | 0.954677438 | A        |
|     1 |  1 | 1/1/18 | 0.148103273 | 0.976617504 | B        |
|     2 |  1 | 1/1/18 | 0.365541214 | 0.551642346 | C        |
|     6 |  2 | 1/1/18 | 0.425580038 | 0.725166189 | A        |
|     7 |  2 | 1/1/18 | 0.889677796 | 0.386824338 | B        |
|     8 |  2 | 1/1/18 | 0.835311629 | 0.363802849 | C        |
+-------+----+--------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

``

N.B have left the index numbers in the output df as the same to show the rows I want to get

Note: There are varying numbers of Categories for each ID i.e. can't just get n rows - must use the earliest month for each ID

I have written a python loop that iterates thru each id and then selects the rows with the earliest date but with a large 2+ GB dataset it is very slow.  Hope this is enough information.

If Groupby is not suitable, then other approaches welcome

## Update:

I have done some more investigation on this and come up with a solution
see StackOverflow [Pandas groupby rank date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265362/pandas-groupby-rank-date-time)

### Use groupby and rank to create a DateRank column at the ID level

```
  df['DateRank'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].rank(method='dense', ascending=True)
```

### filter on rank 1 (first entries)

xdf = df[df['DateRank'] == 1.0 ]

### Remove the ranking column

xdf.drop('DateRank', axis=1, inplace=True)

### print the dataframe

xdf

Comment: Could you please provide sample data so people working on the problem can paste it into their editor? The picture of the data is helpful, but its very difficult to replicate.

Comment: I have added the data

Comment: Why would you want to keep index 6 when index 9 has a date that comes before it? (Both of these rows have the same ID and Category)

Comment: Hi Brandon  .. my dates are day/month/year    ... so 1/1/18 comes before 1/2/18  and there was an incorrect date in data before (have now corrected)

Answer (score 0):

The function below will return the smallest value grouped by ID and Category

```
df=df.groupby(["ID","Category"], group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.nsmallest(1, "Date"))
```

Comment: Hi Bran .. thats close but when I run it , it gets the Earliest month where the category occurred  eg if the month is 1/1/18 and the Category is not there, then it picks up the earliest month when it does occur..  I need all the rows in the earliest month NOT all the rows where the Category first occured

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a month column. Then return the row with the smallest month value in each [ID, Category] group.

**Computation**

```
df['month'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: int(x.split("/")[1])) # get month
df = df.groupby(["ID","Category"])['month'].nsmallest(1) # get earliest month for each ID+category observation
```

**Output**

```
print(df.to_string())
  index ID    Date            X            Y Category  month
0     0  1  1/1/18  0.118758835  0.954677438        A      1
1     1  1  1/1/18  0.148103273  0.976617504        B      1
2     2  1  1/1/18  0.365541214  0.551642346        C      1
6     6  2  1/1/18  0.425580038  0.725166189        A      1
7     7  2  1/1/18  0.889677796  0.386824338        B      1
8     8  2  1/1/18  0.835311629  0.363802849        C      1
```

Comment: Hi Brandon .. this looks promising ... the data spans 7 years .. so how do I alter this code to earliest date ( month wont work)