# group by rank continuous date by pandas

Tags: pandas

I refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265362/pandas-groupby-rank-date-time) . But My goal is something different.

**Example**

```
ID    TIME
01    2018-07-11
01    2018-07-12
01    2018-07-13
01    2018-07-15
01    2018-07-16
01    2018-07-17
02    2019-09-11
02    2019-09-12
02    2019-09-15
02    2019-09-16
```

Notice: For each id, the date is unique.

**Expected**

```
ID    TIME        RANK 
01    2018-07-11    1
01    2018-07-12    2
01    2018-07-13    3
01    2018-07-15    1
01    2018-07-16    2
01    2018-07-17    3
02    2019-09-11    1
02    2019-09-12    2
02    2019-09-15    1
02    2019-09-16    2
```

For each id, the rank of continuous date does not change.IF not, the rank restarts.

**Goal**

How to get the result.

**Try**

`df.groupby('ID')['TIME'].rank(ascending=True)` failed

Comment: could you please explain how you get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we check the difference between the dates, which are `> 1 day`. Then we groupby on `ID` and the `cumsum` of these differences and `cumulative count` each group`

```
# df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
s = df['TIME'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=1)).ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1))
df['RANK'] = s.groupby([df['ID'], s.cumsum()]).cumcount().add(1)


   ID       TIME  RANK
0   1 2018-07-11     1
1   1 2018-07-12     2
2   1 2018-07-13     3
3   1 2018-07-15     1
4   1 2018-07-16     2
5   1 2018-07-17     3
6   2 2019-09-11     1
7   2 2019-09-12     2
8   2 2019-09-15     1
9   2 2019-09-16     2
```

Comment: No that would be 1, since the difference would be more than 1 day, in this case 1 year @Ch3steR

Comment: Because of the `ID`, that changed to `2`

Comment: @Erfan Yes, my bad. Now I understood where I was thinking wrong. Nice answer(Upvoted already).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for difference per groups of `TIME` column, compare days for not equal `1` and create groups by cumulative sums, last pass to [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])

new = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)['TIME'].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['ID',new]).cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
   ID       TIME  rank
0   1 2018-07-11     1
1   1 2018-07-12     2
2   1 2018-07-13     3
3   1 2018-07-15     1
4   1 2018-07-16     2
5   1 2018-07-17     3
6   2 2019-09-11     1
7   2 2019-09-12     2
8   2 2019-09-15     1
9   2 2019-09-16     2
```