# group by rank continuous month by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is something different by this post[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509730/group-by-rank-continuous-date-by-pandas#62509858).

**Example**

```
ID    TIME
01    2018-07-01
01    2018-08-01
01    2018-09-01
01    2018-11-01
01    2018-12-01
01    2019-01-01
02    2019-01-01
02    2019-02-01
02    2019-03-01
02    2020-01-01
```

Notice: For each id, the date is unique and the date format is `%Y-%m-01` .The type of `TIME` is datatime.

**Expected**

```
ID    TIME         RANK
01    2018-07-01    1
01    2018-08-01    2
01    2018-09-01    3
01    2018-11-01    1
01    2018-12-01    2
01    2019-01-01    3
02    2019-01-01    1
02    2019-02-01    2
02    2019-03-01    3
02    2020-01-01    2
```

**Try**

```
s = df['TIME'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=30)).ne(pd.Timedelta(days=30))
df['RANK'] = s.groupby([df['ID'], s.cumsum()]).cumcount().add(1)

new = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)['TIME'].diff().dt.days.ne(30).cumsum()
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['ID',new]).cumcount().add(1)
```

But it failed when the continuous `TIME` is `2020-02-01` and `2020-03-01`.

Comment: My solution failed too?

Comment: @jezrael I updated my post. It failed.

Comment: How is the rank related to the TIME ?

Comment: @Hugolmn is the example not clear? Please give more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert datetimes to months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then compare by `MonthEnd` difference of values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with cumulative sums and last is used [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME']).dt.to_period('M')
new = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)['TIME'].diff().ne(pd.offsets.MonthEnd()).cumsum()
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['ID',new]).cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
  ID     TIME  RANK  rank
0   1  2018-07     1     1
1   1  2018-08     2     2
2   1  2018-09     3     3
3   1  2018-11     1     1
4   1  2018-12     2     2
5   1  2019-01     3     3
6   2  2019-01     1     1
7   2  2019-02     2     2
8   2  2019-12     1     1
9   2  2020-01     2     2
```

Comment: would you mind explaining the code, especially row 2

Comment: @Jack - I edit answer with some explanation, I hope working well.