# How to find index where columns continuous months is 6?

Tags: pandas

**Example**

```
df
    id   date 
    A    201901
    A    201902
    A    201903
    A    201904
    A    201905
    A    201906
    A    202006
    A    202007
    A    202008
    B    202008
    B    202009
    B    202109
    B    202110
    B    202111
    C    201901
    C    201902
    C    201903
    C    201904
    C    201905
    C    201906
    C    202006
    C    202007
    C    202008
    C    202009
    C    202010
    C    202011
```

For each id, the `date` is sorted.

**Expected**

I want to find id where there are 6 continuous months. For id `A`, 201901-201906 while id `C` is 202006-2020011

```
 expected_id=['A','C']
```

The type of col date is object

**Try**

I had no idea how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510611/2901002) with aggregate `count`s by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('M')

new = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)['date'].diff().ne(pd.offsets.MonthEnd()).cumsum()

df = df.groupby(['id',new]).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  id  date  count
0  A     1      6
1  A     2      3
2  B     3      2
3  B     4      3
4  C     5      6
5  C     6      6
```

and last filter `id` by equal `6` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
expected_id = df.loc[df['count'].eq(6), 'id'].unique().tolist()
print (expected_id)
['A', 'C']
```